# ¿Cómo almacenar objetos en un archivo directo?

Tags: java

Requiero almacenar en java un objeto que esta asociado con otro en un archivo, para crear un esqueleto de 2300 registros vacíos.

```
 public void crear_esqueletovot() throws FileNotFoundException{
    /*VARIABLES*/
    Votantearch votante = new Votantearch();
    votante = null;
    int i;
    /*INICIO*/
    RandomAccessFile Archvotantes = new RandomAccessFile("Archivo_de_votantes.dat", "rw");
    for(i = 0; i <= 2300;i++){
        Archvotantes.write(votante);
    }
}
```

Comment: realmente no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, ¿podrias ser mas explicito?

Comment: Al momento de almacenar un objeto en un archivo la manera más fácil es usar ObjectOutputStream pero esto los almacena de manera secuencial y lo que quiero es poder registrar los objetos de manera directa usando seek.